# CSS/JS Slider issue with loop

Tags: javascript, css, slider

I have an issue with CSS/JS slider.
I've used simple method to make it work - bigger element (`container`) inside smaller (`area`) with hidden overflow.
I have buttons above slider `btn` & `btn2` to control movement of bigger element (`containter`)

The **issue** is that it only work until the "first slide" (blue) is reached, then its not possible to slide to second one (red).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/26r32hb6

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.btn');
var button2 = document.querySelector('.btn2');
var container = document.querySelector('.container');

button.style.background = 'blue';
button2.style.background = 'blue';
container.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

button.onclick = function() {  
   if (container.style.left == 0) {  
     container.style.left = '-100.5%';    
     container.style.backgroundColor = 'red';     
     button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
     button2.style.backgroundColor = 'red';}
else if (container.style.left == '-100.5%') {
  container.style.left = '-200.5%';
  container.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';   
  button.style.backgroundColor = 'purple'; 
  button2.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';    
}
};
button2.onclick = function() {
  if (container.style.left == '-100.5%') { 
    container.style.left = 0; 
    container.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';  
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    button2.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';}
  else if (container.style.left == '-200.5%') { 
    container.style.left = '-100.5%';
    container.style.backgroundColor = 'red';      
    button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    button2.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
};
```

```css
.wrapbtns {
  width: 365px;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
.btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
   float: right;
}
.btn2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.btn, .btn2 {
  transition-duration: 1s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;

}
.area {
  width: 365px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden; /* This */
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  background: blue;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
.box {
  background: yellow;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 48px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapbtns">
<div class="btn2">-X</div>
<div class="btn">X</div></div>

<div class="area">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="box">a</div>
    <div class="box">b</div>
    <div class="box">c</div>
    <div class="box">d</div>
    <div class="box">e</div>
    <div class="box">f</div>
    <div class="box">g</div>
    <div class="box">h</div>
    <div class="box">i</div>
    <div class="box">j</div>
    <div class="box">k</div>
    <div class="box">l</div>
    <div class="box">m</div>
    <div class="box">n</div>
    <div class="box">o</div>
    <div class="box">p</div>
    <div class="box">q</div>
    <div class="box">r</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you already solved this? I don't see the error in the jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, all this can be much easier if you use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com).
but assuming that you only want to do this using javascript, here is my solution:

(Note: even if you use jQuery, the technique is quite similar to the one explained below)

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Bintang/kvowcj6w/

```
var button = document.querySelector('.btn');
var button2 = document.querySelector('.btn2');
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var area = document.querySelector('.area');

button.style.background = 'blue';
button2.style.background = 'blue';
container.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';

var slideCurrent = 0;
var slideTotal = Math.floor(container.offsetWidth / area.offsetWidth);
var slideWidth = area.offsetWidth;
var slideColors = ['blue', 'red', 'purple'];

button.onclick = function() {

  if (slideCurrent < slideTotal - 1) {
    var left = container.style.left;
    var leftInInteger = parseInt(left.replace("px", "")) || 0;
    container.style.left = (leftInInteger - slideWidth) + "px"
    slideCurrent += 1;

    //STYLING
    container.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
    button.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
    button2.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
  }

};
button2.onclick = function() {

  if (slideCurrent > 0) {
    var left = container.style.left;
    var leftInInteger = parseInt(left.replace("px", "")) || 0;
    container.style.left = (leftInInteger + slideWidth) + "px";
    slideCurrent -= 1;

    //STYLING
    container.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
    button.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
    button2.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
  }

};
```

Explanation:

instead of using `if` & `else` to set the specific value of "left" every single time you want to slide, what you want to do is increment the value of "left" every time you want to slide to the left & decrement the value every time you want to slide to the right. (look at the code below)

```
var slideCurrent = 0;
var slideTotal = Math.floor(container.offsetWidth / area.offsetWidth);
var slideWidth = area.offsetWidth;
var slideColors = ['blue', 'red', 'purple'];

button.onclick = function() {

  if (slideCurrent < slideTotal - 1) {
    var left = container.style.left;
    var leftInInteger = parseInt(left.replace("px", "")) || 0;
    container.style.left = (leftInInteger - slideWidth) + "px"
    slideCurrent += 1;

    //STYLING
    container.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
    button.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
    button2.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
  }

};
```

What the code above do is:

1.Every time the button is clicked it will check if the current slide is the last slide

```
if (slideCurrent < slideTotal - 1) {
```

2.if it's not the last slide it will get the current "left" value of the       "container" then it will remove the "px" and turn it from string into an
integer(using the `parseInt()` function), but if the "left" property hasn't been defined it will be replaced with the value of "0"

```
var left = container.style.left;
var leftInInteger = parseInt(left.replace("px", "")) || 0;
```

3.Now that it had the current value of "left" in integer it can decrement the value by the width of the "area"(the smaller element on top) so it will slide to the right and increment the `slideCurrent` variable by one

```
container.style.left = (leftInInteger - slideWidth) + "px"
slideCurrent += 1;
```

4.Lastly, it will set the color of the "container" to the specified color

```
//STYLING
container.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
button.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
button2.style.backgroundColor = slideColors[slideCurrent];
```

Then you can do the opposite to slide to the other direction.

Comment: Thank you! So when I add fourth slide it will still functional?

Comment: yes, basically it is supposed to work, because it's adjusting to the width of the "container", but it will still need some tinkering with the css and javascript to get the effect that you want.

anyway, thx for making my post the answer!